# How to make Accordian Elements Sortable and Draggable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, accordion

I have some pattern for developing dragable/dropable items. The hierarchy follows as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
        $("#Menu").accordion({
            autoHeight: false,
            navigation: true,
            collapsible: true
        });
        $(".sortable").sortable({
                revert: false,
                start: function(e, ui) {
                    draggedItem = ui.item;
                }
        });     
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
            helper: "clone",
            connectToSortable: ".sortable",         
            revert: "true"
        });
});
 </script>
```

The HTML for this is as follows

```
<ul id="Menu">
<li>
    <span class="head">Input</span>
    <div class="childs">
       <ul>    
       <li class="draggable">
            <input type="checkbox"/>
       </li>
       <li class="draggable">
            <input type="radio"/>
       </li>     
       </ul>
    </div>   

    <span class="head">Controls</span>
    <div class="childs">
       <ul>    
       <li class="draggable">
            <input type="file"/>
       </li>
       <li class="draggable">
            <input type="button"/>
       </li>     
       </ul>
    </div>   
</li>
</ul>



<ul class="sortable">
<li> Drag elements Here.</li>
</ul>
```

What the main issue is Without the accordian the Draggable Elements provide some Visual feedback like to where to place them. while when to accordian Structure ( These element :

> ```
> <span class="head">Controls</span>
>
> <div class="childs">
> ```
>
> ) are applied then the Feedback is just within the UL of the Draggable element. I am able to drop them into the Sortable area. I need just to make them provide the feedback which it does without the accordian...